# Spring cloud netflix - Eureka - How to enable CORS

Tags: cors, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to enable CORS within Spring Cloud Eureka server by following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class EurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know why would you need this in Eureka but I have this code in my `Zuul Server` AKA APIGateway on the class annotated with `@EnableZuulProxy`. Somewhat similar to what you have but i am using CorsFilter instead of WebMVCConfigurer, You can give it a shot and see if it helps you.

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grinish. It is exactly what I've done to solve my problem. We introduced Zuul eventually and seems Eureka is not supposed to be exposed to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert this in your main class:

```
public @Bean FilterRegistrationBean<?> corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("Accept");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<Filter>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Full example: https://github.com/EffNox/spring_eureka-rest-operations-angular